# How can I save a new array in iteration in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, loops

Let me preface this by saying that I am new to programming.
I would like to create a new array for each iteration, not add elements to the same array.
How can I create a new array?

If I use E=np.array[(...)]

in my loop, I will be rewriting the array every single time.
I want to have a series of arrays saved so that I can Add them to a data frame later and then sort the arrays by the size of the first element.

Here is my code:

```
E=0
n=0
En=np.array(0)
for x in range(1,7):
    for y in range(1,7):
        for z in range(1,7):
            E= x**2+y**2+z**2
            if E<=14:
                n= n+1
                print( "the energy and the nx, ny, nz is", E,x, y, z)
              E=
            if E> 14:
                    break
                       
print(f'there are {n} cobinations')
```

I don't know. I am new to programming and could not find any answers to "create a new array in the loop", so I did try this:

```
for x in range(1,7):
    for y in range(1,7):
        for z in range(1,7):
            E= x**2+y**2+z**2
            if E<=14:
                n= n+1
                print( "the energy and the nx, ny, nz is", E,x, y, z)
                Exyz=np.array([E,x,y,z])
            if E> 14:
```

This does not allow me to create a new array corresponding to each loop.

Comment: What do you think about using **Array of arrays**?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement *"I want to have a series of arrays saved so that I can Add them to a data frame later"*
I suggest that you initiate an empty dataframe and then append each loop's resulting array to the dataframe with an appropriate unique ID identifying the loop it came from.

```
df=pd.DataFrame() 
E=0
n=0
En=np.array(0)
for x in range(1,7):
    for y in range(1,7):
        for z in range(1,7):
            E= x**2+y**2+z**2
            if E<=14:
                n= n+1
                df=df.append(pd.DataFrame([[E,x,y,z]],columns=['E','x','y','z']))
                Exyz=np.array([E,x,y,z])
            if E> 14:
                break
```

Comment: How would I create a unique name for the array in each loop. 
How would I change the name of the array in each loop? 
It would not let me use the iterating variable in the loop name ei:

for x in range (..)
   for y in range(..)
      for z in range (..)
         xyz=np.array()

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame()  .....(run loop)  ...... Within the loop, when you want to save results, use command below
 df=pd.append(pd.DataFrame([E,x,y,z],columns=['E','x','y','z']))

Comment: You'll get a dataframe of shape (num answers) X 4.  You can easily develop a Unique ID based on the number of iterations, or the position of the loop, and add that to the command that appends data to the dataframe

Comment: I tried this and it gives me an error:

                df=df.append(pd.DataFrame([E,x,y,z],columns=['E','x','y','z']))

I put it in the first If statement

Comment: You need to install those packages to use dataframes. What is your environment? Are you using anaconda? If so, open anaconda prompt in admin mode and run 'conda install numpy', 'conda install pandas'.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

Comment: I am in anaconda and have pandas installed.

Comment: It doesn't like the dimensions of the array. The error reads :

"Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 4)"

Comment: I'm adding working code in the main answer to help you out. If you have pandas and numpy installed this will work

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I know not many people want to help with basic questions. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to upvote the answers that you find helpful so that other people see them first. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you can use an empty list and after that in every iterate append new list to that (if you like to have array, change the list to np.array in last line of code)

```
import numpy as np

E = 0
n = 0
# define empty list
En = []

for x in range(1, 7):
    for y in range(1, 7):
        for z in range(1, 7):
            E = x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2
            if E <= 14:
                n = n + 1
                print("the energy and the nx, ny, nz is", E, x, y, z)
                # append new list to En list
                En.append([E, x, y, z])
            if E > 14:
                break

print(f'there are {n} cobinations')
# if you like to have array,
En = np.array(En)
print(En)
```